# F#: Automatically deleting files in directory

Tags: file, hash, f#, directory

I have a hash map, with each key corresponding to a byte array. The values are the path names of files that share the same byte array.

I would like to write a function that automatically keeps the first file that corresponds to each byte array, and delete the rest from my directory. How may I go about doing so? Will you kindly provide some pseudocode that I can work with?

Thank you.

<strike>EDIT: Here is part of a sample I have written:</strike>

```
let deleteEverythingButTheFirst (someSequence: seq<string>) =
    let mutable index = 0
    while index > 0 && index < Seq.length someSequence do
        File.Delete someSequence.[index]
```

Unfortunately, the part 'someSequence.[index]' is underscored in red, with the error message "The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined". What changes should I make to correct this?

SECOND EDIT: Here is some new code I have written. Feedback will be greatly appreciated.

```
let rec deleteSecondFile (sequenceOfFiles: array<string>) =
    let index = 1
    File.Delete sequenceOfFiles.[index]
    sequenceOfFiles
```

Will this work? What changes can I make?

Answer (score 1):

You've defined `someSequence` as a `seq<string>`, but you're trying to use it as an array; the `someSequence.[index]` is an array indexed accessor.

You can either redefine `someSequence` as an array, or use `Seq.iter` to produce side-effects from each element in a sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are there any other improvements that I can make to my code? I noticed that I am changing the sequence (by deleting items) while iterating through it, which is undesirable. What changes can I make to ensure that it performs properly?

Comment: "... use Seq.iter to produce side-effects from each element in a sequence." Additionally, can you kindly elaborate on this part? Thank you.

Comment: The [documentation of Seq.iter is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340396.aspx) ;)

Comment: Hello Mark, will you kindly look at my second edit and let me know if it will work? What improvements can I make? Thanks.

Comment: @MY_G Have you tried it? Does it do what you want it to do?